# Why attributes is not parsing with simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, simplexml

i'm trying to parse xml to array
here is my sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Service_GetCancelPolicy>
    <GetCancelPolicy_Response>
        <ResNo>ELOKMA190410940</ResNo>
        <HBooking>HBMA1904000294</HBooking>
        <HotelId>WSASIDDPS001302</HotelId>
        <HotelName>Inna Bali Heritage Hotel</HotelName>
        <Policies>
            <Policy FromDate="2019-03-01" ToDate="2019-08-31">
                <RoomCatgCode Name="SULTAN" BFType="NONE">WSMA02045946</RoomCatgCode>
                <ExCancelDays>7</ExCancelDays>
                <ChargeType>Percent</ChargeType>
                <ChargeRate>80.00</ChargeRate>
                <Description></Description>
            </Policy>
        </Policies>
    </GetCancelPolicy_Response>
</Service_GetCancelPolicy>
```

here is the array result i get

```
Array
(
    [GetCancelPolicy_Response] => Array
        (
            [ResNo] => ELOKMA190410940
            [HBooking] => HBMA1904000294
            [HotelId] => WSASIDDPS001302
            [HotelName] => Inna Bali Heritage Hotel
            [Policies] => Array
                (
                    [Policy] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [FromDate] => 2019-03-01
                                    [ToDate] => 2019-08-31
                                )

                            [RoomCatgCode] => WSMA02045946
                            [ExCancelDays] => 7
                            [ChargeType] => Percent
                            [ChargeRate] => 80.00
                            [Description] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And here is how i do it

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Service_GetCancelPolicy><GetCancelPolicy_Response><ResNo>ELOKMA190410940</ResNo><HBooking>HBMA1904000294</HBooking><HotelId>WSASIDDPS001302</HotelId><HotelName>Inna Bali Heritage Hotel</HotelName><Policies><Policy FromDate="2019-03-01" ToDate="2019-08-31"><RoomCatgCode Name="SULTAN" BFType="NONE">WSMA02045946</RoomCatgCode><ExCancelDays>7</ExCancelDays><ChargeType>Percent</ChargeType><ChargeRate>80.00</ChargeRate><Description></Description></Policy></Policies></GetCancelPolicy_Response></Service_GetCancelPolicy>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

print_r($array);
```

my question is why RoomCatgCode attributes which include Name and BFType not showing on array?
if RoomCatgCode value (WSMA02045946) is not there, then RoomCatgCode attributes is on result array like Policy FromDate and ToDate attributes

can anyone guide me how to successfully convert that xml to array?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xml_parser_create()` to create a new XML parser. Use `xml_parse_into_struct()` to parse your XML data into an array structure.

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Service_GetCancelPolicy><GetCancelPolicy_Response><ResNo>ELOKMA190410940</ResNo><HBooking>HBMA1904000294</HBooking><HotelId>WSASIDDPS001302</HotelId><HotelName>Inna Bali Heritage Hotel</HotelName><Policies><Policy FromDate="2019-03-01" ToDate="2019-08-31"><RoomCatgCode Name="SULTAN" BFType="NONE">WSMA02045946</RoomCatgCode><ExCancelDays>7</ExCancelDays><ChargeType>Percent</ChargeType><ChargeRate>80.00</ChargeRate><Description></Description></Policy></Policies></GetCancelPolicy_Response></Service_GetCancelPolicy>';

$handle = xml_parser_create();
/* Parse XML data into an array structure */
xml_parse_into_struct($handle, $xml, $values);
xml_parser_free($handle);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($values);
echo '</pre>';
```

// Output:

```
...

[8]=>
  array(5) {
    ["tag"]=>
    string(12) "ROOMCATGCODE"
    ["type"]=>
    string(8) "complete"
    ["level"]=>
    int(5)
    ["attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(6) "SULTAN"
      ["BFTYPE"]=>
      string(4) "NONE"
    }
    ["value"]=>
    string(12) "WSMA02045946"

...
```

Comment: thanks, this is works but, any advantage using this than simplexml_load_string? is there others way to achive this without changing the array structure? because my problem only exist if the xml has attributes and value, if the xml tag only has attributes or value, it is parse successful

Answer (score 0):

var_dump and print_r don't show nested objects. Try this:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Service_GetCancelPolicy><GetCanc$

$result = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach ($result[0]->children()[0] as $elem) {
   foreach($elem->children()[0] as $x) {
        var_dump($x);
   }
}
```

and you will see the attributes of RoomCatgCode

Comment: yes, var_dump and print_r don't show the nested objects but when i convert using json_encode and json_decode, that object is missing on the result array